# Rails: Foreign keys from same table using foreigner gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, foreign-keys

I'd like to use foreigner to link a table of locations at the database level (Postgres) with the following structure.

I have a clients table with the names of various clients and I have a jobs table with two columns: One for the source client, and one for the End client.

Each Job would have two different Clients.

The source client and end client will be different, so the foreign key for the source client would be stored in its own column, and the foreign key for the destination client would be stored in its own column as well.

So my question: How do I establish that relationship using foreigner? Or am I just approaching this wrong?

Answer (score 0):

To me, this seems like a code smell.  Clients have two roles from what you're describing, one is a 'source client' and the other is a 'end client'.  This detracts from SRP [single responsibility principal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) which makes me think these two should be separate classes.  As an example:

```
class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :clients
  has_many :roles
end

class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :jobs
  has_many :roles, through: :jobs
end

client Role < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :clients
end
```

I made up those class names as you didn't really discuss the role-differences between a 'end client' and a 'source client' but this would give you a better sense of who does what.

Comment: I've been debating with that myself. My intent is to have the system be as flexible as possible since clients can either be the origin or destination.

Fragmenting it into two different classes isn't necessarily a bad thing but should a client exist in both tables, it might be a little more annoying to bring them all in together (especially since the client table would hold additional info like address, phone, etc.

Comment: Sounds like clients can have roles within a specific job.  Am I understanding that correctly?

Comment: So a better way to think of it would be like in shipping. There's a sender and a recipient for each Job. Any client could be the sender and any other client could be the recipient.

Comment: my updated answer should satisfy those requirements!  :)

Answer (score 0):

You could do this

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :source_jobs, class_name: 'Jobs', foreign_key: 'client_id' 
   has_many :end_jobs, class_name: 'Jobs', foreign_key: 'end_client_id'
end
class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :client, as: :source_client
  belongs_to :end_client, class_name: 'Client'
end
```

Then in your jobs table you would have a `client_id` column and an `end_client_id` column 
That should work for your description of the task